# How to disable generation of html folder in Doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

I am creating documentation for project using doxygen want to generate only .chm file. But for now html folder and also .chm file is generating. 
I don't want that html folder to be generated

```
GENERATE_HTML = NO
```

.chm file is not generating but html folder is generating with some file

so how you can disable that folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chm is using html and thus html folder cannot be disabled.

From the documentation:

> The HTML Help Workshop contains a compiler that can convert all HTML
>   output generated by doxygen into a single compiled HTML file (.chm).